# Is this the best way to handle this subdomain issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have a domain called mydomain.com on server1/IP1.
I need to put the subdomain store.mydomain.com on server2/IP2.

Am I right I need to add a new DNS A record for the subdomain at the domain registrar? So the DNS zone would look something like this:

mydomain.com.   1   IN  A   IP1

store.mydomain.com. 1   IN  A   IP2

If this is correct, could you please confirm I am right in thinking if the subdomain was on server1/IP1 (so both the domain and subdomain are on the same server), I would add the new DNS A record for the subdomain at the hosting company's DNS zone rather than the registrar's DNS zone?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know DNS basics?

Comment: Yes, but there is so much conflicting information out there that I wanted to be sure I understood this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a separate server for shop.example.com you will need to provide an A record that points to the server.

If you put example.com and shop example.com on the same server then you can use either an A record or a CNAME record to point shop.example.com to the example.com server.

**You need to make the changes on the name servers for example.com.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You say "If you are using a separate server for shop.example.com you will need to provide an A record that points to the server." Where do I create this A record? For example, if the nameserver for domain.com is XXXX.com, I add the A record at XXXX.com?

Comment: Wherever the DNS for example.com is managed.

Comment: In your DNS management interface. Whereever that is (and somehow I get the idea that is not a professional level thing, so should ot be asked here).

Comment: @Ian, the DNS is typically managed at the domain registrar correct? For example, if I assign the nameservers at the domain registrar, does that mean the domain registrar manages the DNS? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to create a subdomain on the current hosting provider(if both domain registrar and hosting provider is same). Than you have make A record entry for  for the ip address of second server there. After that you need to configue vhosts on your second server with subdomain name and content folder for it.

Comment: Are using any kind of panel or something(cpanel) or you have commandline access only?